# How can I check if an element of an iterable contains something

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a multidimensional iterable `a` and I need to find which elements of `a` have `b` as their first operator. Now I use `[i for i in a if i[0] == b]` but it's terribly slow if `a` is really long. Is there a faster or simpler alternative?
Example: `a = [[5, 8], [6, 7], [5, 4], [8, 5]]`, `b = 5`, expected return is `[[5, 8], [5, 4]]`

Comment: What is a multidimensional iterable? What, **exactly** are you working with? There is no faster way to accomplish a linear search, which is what you are doing. You perhaps could leverage a better data structure. But you need to provide more details.

Comment: What is the iterable? Potentially you could put it into a numpy array if it can be generalised to a multidimensional array

Comment: I said iterable because I'm not exactly sure what to use. Right now I'm using a simple list.

Comment: Please can you add a [mcve]

Comment: An example is added in the question.

Comment: Ok, and so all sublists will be of equal length?

Comment: How much data do you have, and how slow is "terribly slow"? And why exactly do you need it to be faster?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes they are.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel My program is running very slowly so I need to make everything more efficient. I'm not sure that that's what's causing the problem but I'm suspecting it. In the list there are over 5000 sublists and I want my program to run almost instantly. I'm just curious if there's a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: The *first* step to fixing "my program is running very slowly" is becoming sure of "what's causing the problem".

Comment: First of all, run some timing tests to make sure of where the problem is. Trying to fix something that doesn't really cause a problem is a very bad waste of time... Secondly, try to think of another way of constructing your data. For example, maybe checking for `b` **before even appending** to `a`. Construct your result list on the fly

Comment: @KarKnechtel I agree, however this question is not only because I need my program to run faster, but also because of my curiosity if there's a faster way to write the same thing. I'm sure I can work out what's actually the problem, I just thought that I could ask a quick question.

Comment: is it a typo `[i for i in a if a[0] == b]` probably you want `i[0] == b`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I will do the timing test, I'm not only trying to fix the time issue but also looking for other, maybe better ways to write the code. I'm still learning the language so I thought that maybe you could use some other data type to solve this. If there's no answer I will still try to find out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is using numpy array, for example:

```
In [21]: import numpy as np

In [22]: l = np.random.randint(1,10,size=(5000,2))

In [23]: %timeit [i for i in l if i[0] == 5]
1.9 ms ± 49.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit l[l[:,0] == 5]
26.9 µs ± 60 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and about your data example:

```
In [25]: a = np.array([[5, 8], [6, 7], [5, 4], [8, 5]])
    ...: b = 5

In [26]: a[a[:,0] == b]
Out[26]: 
array([[5, 8],
       [5, 4]])
```

Comment: Just for comparison, running with regular lists (5000 sublists of 2 random numbers between 1 and 10, looking for 5 at first element) took 2.2 mili... Even less here: https://VisibleEquatorialProcess.tomerkalish.repl.run

Comment: I have never used numpy so I will try it out!

Answer (score 1):

In the general case of an iterable of iterables of unknown length, I don't know of a faster way. The crux of the problem is that Python is slow, so the fastest way to check equality on the first item of each iterable is to avoid doing it in Python. Depending on how your data is structured, here are a couple of ways to accelerate these comparisons using NumPy (the internals of which are implemented in C, not Python).

## Use a numpy array

...if all your inner iterables are the same length and all elements are the same type.

For example, if you have

```py
some_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

you can format this into a numpy array and do `np.array(some_list)[:, 0]` (or, even better, `np.array(some_list, order="F")[0, :]`, since numpy arrays have row-major memory ordering by default).

## Use a new data structure

...if the first element has special status.

Perhaps you could create a new object to house your iterables instead of a list. For example, instead of

```py
people_list = [['Bruce', 1, 2, 3], ['Sharon', 7, 3, 2, 3, 2], ['Lee', 3]]
```

you could create a new object

```py
class People:
    def __init__(self, names, data):
        assert len(names) == len(data)
        self.names = np.asarray(names)  # A vector of names
        self.data = data

    def get_person_data_by_name(self, name):
        person_matches = np.where(self.names == names)[0]
        if len(person_matches) == 0:
            retrieved_data = None
        elif len(person_matches) == 1:
            retrieved_data = self.data[person_matches[0]]
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Multiple people with that name.")

        return retrieved_data

people = People(['Bruce', 'Sharon', 'Lee'], [[1, 2, 3], [7, 3, 2, 7, 2], [3]])
```

This removes the restriction that all your iterables have to be the same length, but imposes other limits on your data.